# passing numeric parameter on ansible variable array

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I got this ansible variable array, weblogic[1].name which will give me the name of the second array "manageServer1".

weblogic: [
   {
     name: "adminServer"
     address: "1.1.1.1"
     port: 1701
     ssl: 1702
   },
   {
     name: "manageServer1"
     address: "1.1.1.2"
     port: 1703
     ssl: 1704
   },
]

How can I pass parameter x=1 on the array, this one won't work, weblogic[x].name or weblogic['x'].name?

I'm working on Ansible 2.6-2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Commas are missing in the lists. See example below.

```
> cat test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    weblogic:
      - { name: "adminServer", address: "1.1.1.1", port: 1701, ssl: 1702 }
      - { name: "manageServer1", address: "1.1.1.2", port: 1703, ssl: 1704 }
  tasks:
    - debug: var=weblogic[item].name
      loop:
        - 0
        - 1


> ansible-playbook test.yml | grep weblogic
    "weblogic[item].name": "adminServer"
    "weblogic[item].name": "manageServer1"
```

Comment: If I add x:1 on the vars:, it's fine.  But as an extra-vars like -e x=1, it won't, ansible will throw "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED".  I'm using ansible 2.7.1.

Comment: This one works! ansible-playbook -v -e '{"x": 1}' test.yml  @Vladimir Botka --thanks a lot to shed some lights on this!

Comment: You're welcome. Read the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line). Simple quotes would be enough.